# akka.net Stashing messages during a specific state of an actor

Tags: akka.net

I have an actor (Person) that I want to be able to stash the messages during a state.  The issue is that I am not sure how to best to accomplish this.

Lets say I have a few commands.

```
ChangeAddress
ChangePhoneNumber
BeginMove
FinishMove
```

While I am in the middle of a move (After BeginMove has started and before FinishMove) I want to prevent updates to Address and PhoneNumber and just replay any events after the move is finished.  I am using a ReceivePersistentActor and each command is a different class.

Right now I was thinking about a status flag on the actor but though the become/unbecome functionality would be a more natural fit but can't see how to apply it to the different commands.

Also as a side question is there a good pattern for breaking up the amount of commands and recovers that have to be written as an actor needs to handle more commands/events?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the flow I think you need

Answer (score 5):

Akka already has this built in:

http://getakka.net/docs/working-with-actors/Stashing%20Messages

You would stash messages in one state as they are received, then unstash when you are ready to transition to the relevant state. The stashed messages then go to the front of the mailbox for processing.

In your example you would receive a `BeginMove` command and transition to a Moving state by calling `Become(Moving)`. The next time a message is processed you will be in this new state. Inside your Moving method, you would configure the `Receive<ChangeAddress>`message handlers to stash the message and all the other handlers to have whatever behaviour you want whilst Moving. At some point in the future you need a `FinishMove` command that changes your behaviour back to what it was before you started the move and unstashes all messages. At this point all stashed messages will begin to be processed in your original behaviour state. **This is all non-blocking**.

```
void OriginalState()
    {
        Receive<ChangeAddress>(s =>
        {
             // change address logic
        });

        Receive<BeginMove>(msg =>
        {
            Become(Moving);
        }
    }

void Moving()
    {
        Receive<ChangeAddress>(s =>
        {
            Stash.Stash();
        });

        Receive<FinishMove>(msg =>
        {
            Become(OriginalState);
            Stash.UnstashAll();
        }
    }
```

See [switchable behaviours](http://getakka.net/docs/working-with-actors/Switchable%20Behaviors) for more example code on how to configure your states to handle your message types.

One way to break things up is to delegate behaviour to child actors if appropriate, but it becomes more of a design issues at that stage.

Answer (score 0):

first things first: as long as there is no PipeTo() calls - there is nothing to change.

Every actor processes one messages at a time, so when it get a list of requests they will be processed in received order, one by one, in a sequence.

To avoid interruption when processing a long running call  (like using db) - I'm stacking my actor - please see an example with receiving actor. This allows to:

1. stop processing inbox
2. prevents stopping method by dispatcher (timeout)
3. avoids using a stash as it is not needed

   ```
   public class ProcessActor : ReceiveActor{

    public ProcessActor() {

       Receive < ChangeAddress > (
           message =  > {
               BecomeStacked(ProcessingOrDoNothing);
               //{do the job here}
               UnbecomeStacked();
           });
    }

     public void ProcessingOrDoNothing(){}

   }
   ```

Comment: Can you expand on what BecomeStacked and UnbecomeStacked do? Can you post the code?

Comment: those are akka internals, and are used to change actor state. When state is changed and there is no `Receive` then mailbox processing is halted, unbecomeStacked reverts previous stacked command.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'd forgotten about those as I've always used Become.

Comment: I think the piece I am missing is that this appears to cause ChangeAddress to hold items in the mailbox while still allowing the other ChangePhoneNumber messages to go through.  Also I want ChangeAddress behavior to modify when I receive a BeginMove command and unbecome when I receive a FinishedMove command.  I can provide a more complete example if it would help of what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Also, I thought calling Become and Unbecome within a single message processing wouldn't actually do anything, as it is only the next message processed that gets the new behaviour? I.e. in this example the only code that does something is the {do the job here} part, as you are Becoming and Unbecoming within the same message, this cancelling each other out

Comment: in this scenario become/unbecome are used as  a safe guards to prevent killing an actor for timeouting when processing the message. as i mentioned in the beginning, actor itself process one message a time, so you requirement is fulfilled.